# IE9 not detecting font installed on PC

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use the FlashDLig font on my website. Now I do have the font installed on my PC(Chrome, FF displays it fine), but for some reason IE does not pick it up. I've also used the @font-face declaration but with no avail(I assume it would not work since @font-face installs a font not present on your PC right?). What can I do to fix that?

Regards
David

Comment: Can you post your `@font-face` declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE9 uses .woff instead of .eot files. You can upload your font to http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator to get the different variations.

Needless to say you should upload the font files to your web server since visitors of your website can't access the font files on your PC.

Comment: -1 since hosting fonts on your site just like any other static media is a perfectly legitimate technique

Comment: He specifically says the font is on his PC. But I see how my answer can be confusing, thanks for the heads up.